# Delegate from Obj-C into Swift - method is never executed

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, delegates, protocols

Before I was using NSNotificationEvents, but as I know I should be using delegate because of 1:1 relations (it will be used only in one place in code).

Basically Im new to objective-C and swift (Im JavaScript guy) and the code that I created after a few hours of reading and checking - it just doesnt work, because self.delegate in not defined.

Im trying to delegate "an event" from objective-C code to swift code. NSNotificationEvents works like charm, but I want to make it with protocols / delegate.

I guess, I just missing how to exactly initialize the delegate protocol.

ProtocolDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ProtocolDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) delegateMethod: (id)data;
@end
```

Event.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import "ProtocolDelegate.h"

@interface Event : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, ProtocolDelegate>
    @property(nonatomic, weak)id <ProtocolDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Event.m
(someMethod is executed from JavaScript React-native code, but it shouldn't be any difference from what I know)

```
#import "Event.h"


@implementation Event

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(Events);
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(someMethod: (NSString*)parameter) {
    NSDictionary* data = @{@"parameter": parameter};

    NSLog(@"This I can see");
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(delegateMethod:)]) {
        NSLog(@"This I can not see");
        [self.delegate delegateMethod:data];
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ProtocolDelegate {

    // Xcode has automatically created this method
    func delegateMethod(_ data: Any!) {
        os_log("ON AUCTION");
    }

}
```

I want delegateMethod inside ViewController to be executed.

Or maybe I get the whole idea wrong? Objective-C is a bit confising to me.

Comment: Did you forget to set `delegate` of `event` to `ViewController`? I didn't see it in your code.

Comment: What do you mean? ProtocolDelegate is imported in ViewController.swift, and builded successfully. hm.

Comment: If you keep an `Event` object inside `ViewController`, you will have something like `event.delegate = self`. Maybe you should research more about delegate pattern.

Comment: No, I dont. The Event instance is initialized by react-native bridge. It's not used any where outside.

1. react-native code is calling Event::someMethod(someStringParameter),<br>
2. someMethod should call delegateMethod() which I was hoping will execute some code from swift. 

I guess It's wrong way to do it hm..

Comment: That’s why your code doesnt work. You should add the code where you use event and how event and view controller relate to each other

Comment: oke, so in this case NSNotificationCenter will fit better.